# Java, not applicable for the arguments,affine transform?

Tags: java, affinetransform

```java
public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(100,100,100,100);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
        transform.rotate(
                Math.toRadians(45), rectangle.getX() + rectangle.width/2,
                rectangle.getY() + rectangle.height/2
        );
        g2d.draw(transform); 
}
```

I am trying to rotate a rectangle around a center, but its not working.
I am getting this error:

> The method draw(Shape) in the type Graphics2D is not applicable for the arguments (AffineTransform)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that you cannot call this method with transform.

You should try to call `setTransform` first and then `draw` the rectangle.

```java
public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(100,100,100,100);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
        transform.rotate(
                Math.toRadians(45), rectangle.getX() + rectangle.width/2,
                rectangle.getY() + rectangle.height/2
        );
        g2d.setTransform(transform);
        g2d.draw(rectangle); 
}
```